# Column( header) sub-string replace in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

- I want to rename column name by replacing a sub string.

  In below example i have to remove "xy" from each column.
  Is there any predefined function or do i need to create UDF ?

> ```
> xy.col1   xy.col2
>       2         3
>       3         5
>       4         4
>       5         8
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by making a dictionary of original column names and the cleaned column names (*here I am splitting on the dot and selecting the right character after split*) , also note the backtick when doing so since the columns have a dot in them "`"

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

d = dict(zip(df.columns,[i.split('.')[-1] for i in df.columns]))
df.select(*[F.col(f"`{k}`").alias(v) for k,v in d.items()]).show()
```

---

```
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|   2|   3|
|   3|   5|
|   4|   4|
|   5|   8|
+----+----+
```